# When using Let's Encrypt certbot, how do I restart/reload a network service only once and only if the cerificate was actually renewed?

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot, ssl-certificate-renewal

The `certbot` command provides two hooks that run after automated renewals, from the docs:

> ```
>  --post-hook POST_HOOK
>                        Command to be run in a shell after attempting to
>                        obtain/renew certificates. Can be used to deploy
>                        renewed certificates, or to restart any servers that
>                        were stopped by --pre-hook. This is only run if an
>                        attempt was made to obtain/renew a certificate. If
>                        multiple renewed certificates have identical post-
>                        hooks, only one will be run. (default: None)
>  --deploy-hook DEPLOY_HOOK
>                        Command to be run in a shell once for each
>                        successfully issued certificate. For this command, the
>                        shell variable $RENEWED_LINEAGE will point to the
>                        config live subdirectory (for example,
>                        "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com") containing the
>                        new certificates and keys; the shell variable
>                        $RENEWED_DOMAINS will contain a space-delimited list
>                        of renewed certificate domains (for example,
>                        "example.com www.example.com" (default: None)
> ```

This issue is outlined in [this (now closed) LE thread](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/is-renew-hook-run-after-each-certificate-renewal-if-more-than-one-renewal/134104) and is basically about minimising interruption to services. `POST_HOOK` executes every time an *attempt* to renew is made even if no certificates were issued, though only once. This makes it possible to unnecessarily restart services. `DEPLOY_HOOK` runs for each and every *successful* certificate renewal. If one uses `DEPLOY_HOOK`, and has multiple certificates, each service may restart multiple times when once is enough. [More info on renewal hooks here.](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewing-certificates)

I use an issuance method that does not interrupt my services at all, e.g.:

```sh
certbot certonly --webroot ...
```

or

```sh
certbot certonly --dns-PROVIDER ...
```

I want to restart/reload each dependent service only once, and only if its certificate actually changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to overcome this limitation by using **both** hooks in combination with a simple script. Instead of each successful renewal immediately triggering a reload/restart, its `--deploy-hook`/`renew_hook` only *marks* the service for an action (by creating temporary files under `/run`), then when the `--post-hook`/`post_hook` runs, it checks for marked services and performs the necessary actions only once. This guarantees that nothing happens to a service unless a certificate it depends on actually changed, and it only happens once.

For example, to reload nginx, and restart vsftpd when a certificate they share is renewed:

```bash
certbot certonly ... \
    --deploy-hook '/usr/local/sbin/read-new-certs-services nginx --restart vsftpd' \
    --post-hook /usr/local/sbin/read-new-certs-services
```

Another certificate may be web-only, so it would have these hook parameters:

```bash
certbot certonly ... \
    --deploy-hook '/usr/local/sbin/read-new-certs-services nginx' \
    --post-hook /usr/local/sbin/read-new-certs-services
```

The script `/usr/local/sbin/read-new-certs-services` is this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

run_base=/run
dir_reloads="$run_base/new-cert-reloads"
dir_restarts="$run_base/new-cert-restarts"

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    some=0
    dir="$dir_reloads"
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        case $1 in
            -h|--help)
                >&2 cat <<-'EOHELP'
                    Usage:

                      read-new-certs-services [-l|-s] service1 [[-l|-s] service2]
                      or
                      read-new-certs-services

                      When called without arguments, marked services will be reloaded or restarted.

                    Arguments:

                      -h, --help
                        This help.

                      -l, --reload
                        Mark all subsequently listed services for reloading. This is the default.

                      -s, --restart
                        Mark all subsequently listed services for restarting.
                    EOHELP
                exit
                ;;
            -l|--reload)
                dir="$dir_reloads"
                ;;
            -s|--restart)
                dir="$dir_restarts"
                ;;
            *)
                if [ -n "$1" ]; then
                    some=1
                    run_file="$dir/$1"
                    if [ ! -f "$run_file" ] && ! install -D /dev/null "$run_file"; then
                        >&2 echo "Service could not be marked: $run_file"
                        exit 1
                    fi
                fi
                ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
    if [ $some -eq 0 ]; then
        >&2 echo 'No service(s) specified.'
        exit 1
    fi
    exit
fi

if [ -d "$dir_restarts" ]; then
    find "$dir_restarts" -mindepth 1 -printf '%P\t%p\n' | while IFS="$(printf '\t')" read -r svc run_file; do
        systemctl restart "$svc" && rm "$run_file"
        # no need to reload as well if restarting
        run_file="$dir_reloads/$svc"
        if [ -f "$run_file" ]; then
            rm "$run_file"
        fi
    done
fi

if [ -d "$dir_reloads" ]; then
    find "$dir_reloads" -mindepth 1 -printf '%P\t%p\n' | while IFS="$(printf '\t')" read -r svc run_file; do
        systemctl reload "$svc" && rm "$run_file"
    done
fi
```

This script must be used on both hooks for every certificate issue so that none use a conflicting method of restarting services.

You can change existing certificate renewals to use this method by editing their `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*.conf` files to contain hooks like this in the `[renewalparams]` section:

```ini
renew_hook = /usr/local/sbin/read-new-certs-services nginx -s vsftpd
post_hook = /usr/local/sbin/read-new-certs-services
```